# How can I multiply these sums?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

How do I multiply this? Is it even possible given that one sum is infinite?

$$
x^{n}\left[\,\sum_{r = 0}^{n}\left(-1\right)^{r}x^{mr}\,\right]
\left[\,\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}{n + k - 1 \choose k} x^{k}\,\right]
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can collect the like powers of $x^k$ like so:
$$
\begin{align}
x^n\left[\sum_{r=0}^n(-1)^rx^{mr}\right]\left[\sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{n+k-1}{k} x^k\right]
&=\sum_{k=n}^\infty\left[\sum_{r=0}^n(-1)^r\binom{k-mr-1}{k-mr-n}\right]x^k\\
&=\sum_{k=n}^\infty\left[\sum_{r=0}^{\min\left(\left\lfloor\frac{k-n}{m}\right\rfloor,n\right)}(-1)^r\binom{k-mr-1}{n-1}\right]x^k\\
\end{align}
$$
noting that $\displaystyle\binom{n}{k}=0$ when $k\lt0$.

Comment: Thank you! But I don't understand the $(k-n)/m$ part. Can you explain why is that so?

Comment: @kanbhold: $\binom{n}{k}=\binom{n}{n-k}$ as long as $n\ge0$. However, this breaks down when $n\lt0$. In order to prevent erroneous terms when $r$ is too big, we need to limit its size so that $k-mr-n\ge0$ (the erroneous terms happen when $k-mr-1\lt0$ and $n-1\ge0$).

Comment: @kanbhold: Note that when $r\gt\frac{k-n}{m}$, $k-mr-1\lt n-1$, so the binomial coefficients are $0$ anyway until $r\gt\frac{k-1}{m}$; at that point, the negative binomial coefficients come into play. These are what the cap on $r$ is trying to avoid.

Comment: @kanbhold: I have now limited $r$ so that it doesn't get larger than $n$.

Answer (score 0):

The first factor with the finite alternating geometric sum over $r$ is $$\frac{1-(-x^m)^{n+1}}{x^m+1}$$. The second infinite sum over $k$ is $\frac{1}{(1-x)^n}$.

Comment: That does not answer the core of the question.